# next and current element in a collection

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I've been wondering if I can make this code more pythonic

```
for i in xrange(len(my_list) - 1)):
    first = my_list[i]
    second = my_list[i + 1]
```

something like:

```
for first,second in foo(my_list):
```

In Scala I would use `(my_list.tail, my_list).zipped`

I'm looking for a solution that will NOT allocate extra memory like `zip(my_list,my_list[1:])`

Comment: `zip` does not allocate extra memory on Py3k

Comment: @frostnational: this is Python 2; `xrange()` is used.

Comment: @frostnational but slicing does, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh sliding is the keyword to google it. Thx.